# Drupal Views Slideshow + Galleria

Tags: views

Image Gallery with the use of [View slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) does a trick for me.

what I need :

But for thumbnails & for main image galleria provide image crop with 4 options like `height, width etc.`

Is there any way that we can use custom image style that we have added from back-end to create those thumbnails?

Please Guys Suggest. I stuck in this since many time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel) module for slideshow. I think this is what you want.